# Making a List<T> of a type created via Add-Type -TypeDefinition in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a class that I define in inline C# in powershell:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    public class SomeClass {
        string name;
        public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
        int a, b;
        public int A { get { return a; } set { a = value; } }
        public int B { get { return b; } set { b = value; } }
    }
"@
```

I can instantiate it:
    $someClass= New-Object SomeClass -Property @{
        'Name' = "Justin Dearing";
        "A" = 1;
        "B" = 5;
    };

But I cannot instantiate a list of it:

> $listOfClasses = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[SomeClass];

Doing so gets me the following:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [[System.Collections.Generic[SomeClass]]]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:12 char:28
+ $listOfClasses = New-Object <<<<  [System.Collections.Generic[SomeClass]]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that is not directly supported in PowerShell. Here is [a solution](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/08/18/creating-generic-types-in-powershell/), which provides a `New-GenericObject` script; that does some reflection in order to create the correct type.

Comment: I ended up working around the problem, but will use this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to simple make a List<SomeClass> factory in the SomeClass definition like so:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class SomeClass {
        string name;
        public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
        int a, b;
        public int A { get { return a; } set { a = value; } }
        public int B { get { return b; } set { b = value; } }

        public static List<SomeClass> CreateList () { return new List<SomeClass>(); }
    }
"@
```

Then you can instantiate a list like so `$listOfClasses = [SomeClass]::CreateList();`

Comment: It's an answer, not a clarification. While I don't think its the best answer (hence me not marking it correct) it is an answer to my question so I stuck it in the answers. Jeff and Joel have repeatedly said its ok to answer your own questions.

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question, otherwise I would have flagged this. I am saying that this is not the exact solution and should have been part of the question as a possible alternative, but it doesn't answer the general question, as it is an alternative only in the specific case of when your are adding the type and you have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

read this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2009/10/12/generic-list-and-powershell.aspx

Comment: Same idea as @driis's answer.